# problemas com bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

estou usando o jsfiddle para aprender bootstrap, porém estou com problemas ao fazer o conteúdo aparecer na mesma linha. o meu conteúdo no jsffidle está aparecendo em duas linhas (queria uma linha e 2 colunas)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red;">
            <h4>teste</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: black;">
            <h4>teste</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

meu jdfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hurv9jjr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você especificou apenas classes para `dispositivos médios (>992px)`  na suas `divs` com o  `col-md-6`. Ou seja, o [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) do bootstrap só esta sendo ativado pra resoluções acima de 992px e a janela de preview do JSFiddle é inferior à este tamanho.

Para que seja mostrado da forma correta basta acrescentar as classes que especificam o grid pra resoluções menores:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="background-color: red;">
        <h4>teste</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="background-color: black;">
        <h4>teste</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Recomendo que dê uma pincelada no funcionamento do grid do boostrap. Boa sorte.